# Workflow error: Invalid data has been used to update list item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, updatelistitems

My list workflow on SharePoint 2010 foundation is created in SPDesigner. Sometimes it raises an error (from ULS log):

> "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are
>   trying to update may be read only." level Unexpected.

Periodicity is  about 5% of all instances. How to get more info about this error ? WF History log cannot help me, because when WF crash there is only

> "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more
>   columns for the item require a different type of information." in
>   history.

Error in Workflow history list : [image]

Comment: what's the fields that you tried to update it ? also what's the updated value

Comment: If I'd know it, I solve problem. But there is many fields to update. I think, the problem is in Person field type, but I cannot identify which one.

Comment: can you give workflow screenshot

Comment: @Monica: printscreen from designer or XOML source ?

Comment: Designer screenshot. Also try to add log to history step after 3-4 steps to get the steps which causing the problem. Then we can check that step in detail for error.

Comment: @Monica: I have updated my original question, added printscreen from WF history list. But screenshots from Designer IMHO are not useful. You will not see details, and the workflow is too big to post it complete.

Comment: can you provide screenshot for the person field you mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I found the reason. Main list and some other related lists contains People fields (about 30 fields of this type). I cannot determine, which one (or more) value is corrupted during workflow processing. I talked with customer IT department and have got an information:  **some peoples were disabled in AD**. In SharePoint groups they are normally visible , enabled and operable (I can in EditForm select such a person and submit form). So I delete all the disabled peoples in SP groups, edit all error records, changed the values to "correct persons" and now it seems to be OK. Thanks for your help.